# Checking whether a complex function has an antiderivative

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

There is a function $f(z)$ given:
$$f(z) = \frac{z}{z^2 + 1}.$$
$z \in \Omega = \mathbb{C} \setminus \overline{D(0,1)}$,

where $D(0, 1)$ is a disc centered at zero and its radius is equal to 1.
I am to check whether the given function has an antiderivative.

### What am I to check?

To my mind it is necessary to check if

1. integral over any line from point $a$ to point $b$ is equal to $0$.

Is this condition equivalent to the statement that $f$ is holomorphic on every single-coherent area which is included in $\Omega$?

### Calculations

If $1$ is true how can I check if integrals over any line is equal to $0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint:* Consider the integral of $f$ along the circle of radius $2$ centered at the origin. If $f$ has an antiderivative, then this integral is zero.

If you can, compute the integral using residues using that
$$
\operatorname{Res}(f,c) = \frac{g(c)}{h'(c)}
$$
when $f(z) = \dfrac{g(z)}{h(z)}$ and $h(c)=0$ and $h'(c)\ne0$.

Otherwise, compute the integral directly. Using a square instead of a circle will be simpler.

Comment: Thank you. However I haven't had a lecture about residues yet. Can it be done without them?

Comment: Thank you! I will try to compute this integral. Why are we centering the square or the circle at the origin if $z\in \mathbb{C} \setminus \overline{D(0,1)}$?

Comment: @Hendrra, the curve is totally contained in $\Omega$.

Comment: Thank you, now it's obvious! I did the calculations and I think that $f(z)$ has no antiderivative.